# An equivalent for "It is not a divine message to..." in American English

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

In my country, whereas it has an eastern, religious type of the culture when someone wants to say that an event must happen 100% in order to achieve something or when someone wants to say that it is not "very" necessary to do something and generally when someone wants to emphasize that a specific belief is not very necessary, says:

> - It is not a divine message / voice for you to do that.
> - It is not a divine message / voice that it must happen.
>     etc.

I am looking for an idiom, expression in AE for "divine message / voice" in the ways that I used in above self-made / translated sentences.
I would be thankful if you could help me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "must happen 100% in order to achieve something" or "very necessary".

Comment: I agree; your first sentence is very unclear.  What do you mean "an event must happen 100%" **or** that it is not "very" necessary to do something?  Those seem like two completely different things.

Comment: must happen 100% in order to achieve something = In order to something else happen, something must happen and there is no other way round

Comment: You are right @stangdon . They are completely different situations, but in my language in both of these senses we use the same idiom which Chenmunka mentioned to. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common phrase is: [*"It is not cast in stone"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=idiom+cast+in+stone&oq=idiom+cast+in+stone) or "*It is not carved in stone"*

Although this does have a religious origin, which may not be what you wish.

Moses brought down the ten commandments on tablets of stone.  Thus, *cast in stone* suggests the word of God.  The words cannot be altered.

Comment: Exactly it was what I needed. Thank you very much Chenmunka. :)

Comment: Another phrasing of the same idea is "set in stone". Just one more option; making a comment since it's a variation on a theme.